# Angular Firestore make this query change depending on a condition

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how do I make this query change depending on a condition

```
 let query = (ref: CollectionReference)=>{
    return ref.where("dateOrd", ">=", this.dateIn)
    .where("dateOrd", "<=", this.dateOu)
    .where("status", "==", this.staTus)
    .where("seller", "==", this.idseller)  
    .where("ptype", "in", this.ptype)
    .orderBy("dateOrd", "desc")
    .orderBy("creado", "desc")
    .limit(5000)
  }
```

for example, if a condition is met, change the query

Something like this **(this fails)**

```
if (typeof this.idCli!="undefined"){
  query = query.where("client", "==", this.idCli)
}
```

but, How do I do that multiple query?

Please Help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore queries follow a builder pattern, where each call to `where()` returns a new query.

So you just repeat calls to `where` like in your second fragmment:

```
let query = (ref: CollectionReference)=>{
    let q = ref.where("dateOrd", ">=", this.dateIn)
    .where("dateOrd", "<=", this.dateOu)
    .where("status", "==", this.staTus)
    .where("seller", "==", this.idseller)  
    .where("ptype", "in", this.ptype)
    .orderBy("dateOrd", "desc")
    .orderBy("creado", "desc")
    .limit(5000)
    if (typeof this.idCli!="undefined"){
      q = q.where("client", "==", this.idCli)
    }
    return q;
  }
```

If your other conditions are also are dynamic, you can do the same for those:

```
let q = ref;
if (typeof this.dateIn!="undefined"){
  q = q.where("dateOrd", ">=", this.dateIn)
}
if (typeof this.dateOu!="undefined"){
  q = q.where("dateOrd", "<=", this.dateOu)
}
...
q = q.limit(5000)
if (typeof this.idCli!="undefined"){
  q = q.where("client", "==", this.idCli)
}
return q;
```